# Img src is being encoded when setting it to be an SVG

Tags: typescript

I have a node that is an SVG element.  It was generated by D3.

In my Angular 2 app I need to take that element and convert it to a png using dom-to-image.

My problem is when I take the SVG element and set it to the src of the img element, the SVG code is encoded.

How do I just have the actual string put into the src?

This is my code. Basically I am creating a div, then create an img, and set the img src to be what is in node.

```
  var divelem = document.createElement('div');
  var imgelem = document.createElement('img');
  imgelem.height = 400;
  imgelem.width = 300;
  imgelem.src = node.outerHTML;
  //imgelem.src = decodeURI(imgelem.src)
```

This is the value of `node.outerHTML`:

```
<svg width="166" height="195"><g trantsform="translate(86,[object Window])"><g class="layer" id="annual-stacked-bar" height="NaN" style="stroke-dasharray: 3, 3; fill: rgb(193, 191, 193);"><rect y="36.29999999999998" x="12" height="158.70000000000002" width="77.4"><text y="182.9" x="25.8" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">NaNundefined%</text></rect></g><g class="layer" id="annual-stacked-bar" height="NaN" style="stroke-dasharray: 3, 3; fill: rgb(142, 86, 158);"><rect y="15.669000000000011" x="12" height="20.630999999999972" width="77.4"><text y="31.07699999999998" x="25.8" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">NaNundefined%</text></rect></g><g><text dy=".9em" y="28.299999999999983" height="36.29999999999998">---------------------</text></g><g><text dy=".9em" x="100" y="26.299999999999983" height="36.29999999999998" style="fill: rgb(128, 128, 132);">Expected</text></g></g></svg>
```

`imgelem.src` is

> "http://localhost:4208/%3Csvg%20width=%22166%22%20height=%22195%22%3E%3Cg%20trantsform=%22translate(86,[object%20Window])%22%3E%3Cg%20class=%22layer%22%20id=%22annual-stacked-bar%22%20height=%22NaN%22%20style=%22stroke-dasharray:%203,%203;%20fill:%20rgb(193,%20191,%20193);%22%3E%3Crect%20y=%2236.29999999999998%22%20x=%2212%22%20height=%22158.70000000000002%22%20width=%2277.4%22%3E%3Ctext%20y=%22182.9%22%20x=%2225.8%22%20style=%22fill:%20rgb(255,%20255,%20255);%22%3ENaNundefined%%3C/text%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%20class=%22layer%22%20id=%22annual-stacked-bar%22%20height=%22NaN%22%20style=%22stroke-dasharray:%203,%203;%20fill:%20rgb(142,%2086,%20158);%22%3E%3Crect%20y=%2215.669000000000011%22%20x=%2212%22%20height=%2220.630999999999972%22%20width=%2277.4%22%3E%3Ctext%20y=%2231.07699999999998%22%20x=%2225.8%22%20style=%22fill:%20rgb(255,%20255,%20255);%22%3ENaNundefined%%3C/text%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20dy=%22.9em%22%20y=%2228.299999999999983%22%20height=%2236.29999999999998%22%3E---------------------%3C/text%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20dy=%22.9em%22%20x=%22100%22%20y=%2226.299999999999983%22%20height=%2236.29999999999998%22%20style=%22fill:%20rgb(128,%20128,%20132);%22%3EExpected%3C/text%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E"

decoding it didn't help as it isn't a valid url, so I am not certain how to get the value in node.outerHTML to be in imgelem.src.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to do this, but no matter what I do, once it is put into `src` then it gets encoded.

```
  imgelem.src = 
   '<svg width="166" height="195"><g trantsform="translate(86,[object Window])"><g class="layer" id="annual-stacked-bar" height="NaN" style="stroke-dasharray: 3, 3; fill: rgb(193, 191, 193);"><rect y="36.29999999999998" x="12" height="158.70000000000002" width="77.4"><text y="182.9" x="25.8" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">NaNundefined%</text></rect></g><g class="layer" id="annual-stacked-bar" height="NaN" style="stroke-dasharray: 3, 3; fill: rgb(142, 86, 158);"><rect y="15.669000000000011" x="12" height="20.630999999999972" width="77.4"><text y="31.07699999999998" x="25.8" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">NaNundefined%</text></rect></g><g><text dy=".9em" y="28.299999999999983" height="36.29999999999998">---------------------</text></g><g><text dy=".9em" x="100" y="26.299999999999983" height="36.29999999999998" style="fill: rgb(128, 128, 132);">Expected</text></g></g></svg>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that to work you must put a string in the `src` attribute of your image, it is not possible to put markup (or SVG in your case)

> `src:` Is a DOMString that reflects the src HTML attribute, containing
>   the full URL of the image including base URI.

See the `Image()` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)

Your best option then, would be to use the [data url syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs),
this is a working example:

```
var svg = '<svg width="166" height="195"><g trantsform="translate(86, ...></svg>'
var serializer = new XMLSerializer()
var data = serializer.serializeToString(svg)
yourImageElement.src = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + data
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: I would never have thought of using this approach.  I finally went to rendering on a canvas and then using that instead, but if I can remove one library I think your approach is better.

Comment: Canvas are great too, if it works for you that's all you need :) happy coding